# PyInstaller does not include imports

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I am having a problem with PyInstaller including any imported custom modules.
I have a main.py that calls a method

```
from Printer.function import Repeat

def main():
    name = input("Your Name: ")
    Repeat(3,name)

    input("Press enter to exit") 

main()
```

Through VS Code, everything is working.

However using pyInstaller, when I run the exe file it throws an error that the module 'function' is not found. 
I am running this command

```
pyinstaller.exe -p K:\HelloWorldEXE\Printer K:\HelloWorldEXE\main.py --onefile
```

Can any one shed some light on this? I don't know how to use hidden-imports or hooks to make it work

Thanks.

Comment: Run it from the directory that the script is in - `K:\HelloWorldEXE> pyinstaller main.py --onefile`

Comment: Do see my solution and let me know if there are any issues.

Comment: Thanks @Legorooj for the answer. It works!

Comment: Feel free to accept or post an answer if the problem is solved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two possible solutions

**1.**

As @Legorooj mentioned try running it from the directory where the script is,e.g.

```
K:\HelloWorldEXE> pyinstaller main.py --onefile
```

**2.**

By default, python only searches current directory. So if you want you can also append the path a bit.

In your script, set the path to your package:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('C:\PathTo\project\package1')
import module1
```

That should fix the issue you were having.

Comment: The trick was, as you guessed, the pythonpath. I wouldn't edit the pythonpath within a script you want to compile, it can mess with the output. Instead, specify the `-p/--path` option to PyInstaller. That will add the specified paths to the pythonpath when PyInstaller is searching for imports. (That option can be used multiple times). Note that running from the directory that the script in worked, because it added that path (the working directory) to the pythonpath.