# No module named using pyinstaller

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I am currently trying to figure out how does pyinstaller works when there are imports involved. Here is the architecture of my project :

```
root
  -> libs
    -> __init__.py
    -> lib2.py
  -> folder
    -> src
      -> __init__.py
      -> lib1.py
      -> main.py
    -> dist
      -> runner.exe
```

What I do is using *pyinstaller* to generate an exe file (with its dependancies that I have excluded of my scheme). In my *main.py*, I modified the sys.path to get it relative using os.path.dirname, so it looks like this : `[/root, /root/libs, /root/folder/src]` (I print it in my code to be sure). After this path manipulation, I have my import lines : `import lib2` and `import lib1` that work when I run my python file normally, but I get the error `No module named lib1` and `No module named lib2` when I run the exe file.

I have been looking at the [doc for imports of Python](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#packages) and at the [doc of pyinstaller](https://pyinstaller.org/en/stable/usage.html), and tested several things that didn't help me get through this.

Comment: This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61033931/pyinstaller-does-not-include-imports

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading more carefully the [doc of pyinstaller](https://pyinstaller.org/en/stable/usage.html#cmdoption-p), I have found the option `-p/--path` that allows to add paths to pythonpath without having to do it inside the Python script. For example `pyinstaller -p /home/usrname/desktop/root/libs:/home/usrname/desktop/folder/src main.py` works perfectly.